# ZFS entering D-State at random

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, zfs, zfsonlinux, crash

I am running ZFS on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ontop of hyper-v.
At random, currently every 2-3 days, ZFS gets stuck.
Samba is non-responsive, File I/O via smb to the ZFS volume ceases and actions on the shell on the volume makes the shell freeze.
Ubuntu is still responsive, only ZFS gets stuck.

Syslog:

> Oct 31 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.002788] INFO: task z_rd_int:1200
> blocked for more than 120 seconds. Oct 31 13:21:07 zfs kernel:
> [160466.002793]       Tainted: P           O      5.4.0-52-generic
> #57-Ubuntu Oct 31 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.002793] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message. Oct 31
> 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.002795] z_rd_int        D    0  1200
> 2 0x80004000 Oct 31 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.002797] Call Trace:
> Oct 31 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.002804]  __schedule+0x2e3/0x740
> Oct 31 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.002806]  schedule+0x42/0xb0 Oct 31
> 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.002807]  io_schedule+0x16/0x40 Oct 31
> 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.002809]  rq_qos_wait+0x106/0x180 Oct 31
> 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.002811]  ? __wbt_done+0x40/0x40 Oct 31
> 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.002812]  ? sysv68_partition+0x2d0/0x2d0

[...]

> Oct 31 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.003297] INFO: task z_wr_iss:1206
> blocked for more than 120 seconds. Oct 31 13:21:07 zfs kernel:
> [160466.003300]       Tainted: P           O      5.4.0-52-generic
> #57-Ubuntu Oct 31 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.003301] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message. Oct 31
> 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.003302] z_wr_iss        D    0  1206
> 2 0x80004000 Oct 31 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.003304] Call Trace:
> Oct 31 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.003306]  __schedule+0x2e3/0x740
> Oct 31 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.003308]  schedule+0x42/0xb0 Oct 31
> 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.003309]  io_schedule+0x16/0x40 Oct 31
> 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.003310]  rq_qos_wait+0x106/0x180 Oct 31
> 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.003312]  ? __wbt_done+0x40/0x40 Oct 31
> 13:21:07 zfs kernel: [160466.003313]  ? sysv68_partition+0x2d0/0x2d0

In HTOP you can see that there are 8 tasks that are hanging in D-State.
I need to reboot the whole VM to get ZFS to respond again.
[image: htop]

Is this phenomenon known? what can be done to prevent ZFS from hanging?
Some info:

Ubuntu 20.04LTS running ontop of Hyper-V

16 Gigs RAM, 16 V-Cores (3950x with ECC RAM).

ZFS Volume is a ZFS-Z1 array with 8 x 5TB drives. Compression is LZ4, no dedup

I tuned L1ARC to only use 6GB of RAM. You can see in the screenshot that the VM still has 5 GB of free RAM when the freeze occurs. So I don't think its an OOM szenario.

Other than the L1Arc size, "xattr=sa" and "sync=never" (I know....) no tuning has been done, everything out of the box.

Comment: Look for failing storage media.

Comment: @MichaelHampton
Is there any way I can look for that?
All devices under /dev seemed to be Okay, there were no messages in the syslog that storage devices became unresponsive.
Also, zpool status lists no errors, even when the threads hang.